# Extreme command shortening

Tags: wget

I'm converting some commands into bar codes for others to easily scan to implement. It cuts down on repetitive typing and typos. The biggest issue are some of the commands that are long, as the longer bar codes are harder to scan.

I've gone so far as registering a tiny domain name, three letters long with a two digit tld. I can host the full commands in scripts there. But I'm trying to shorten them even more.

I started off with:

```
wget -q -O - https://www.originaldomain.tld/script.txt | bash
```

I'm now at:

```
wget -qO- https://tny.tl|bash
```

Is there any way to shorten the wget? I've tried these without any luck.

```
wget -qO- ://domain.tld|bash
wget -qO- domain.tld|bash
wget -qO- domain.tld:443|bash
```

Comment: Are you using barcodes or QR codes. I believe you can squeeze much more information into QR code it you have ability to scan QR codes.

Comment: Looks quite dangerous. How do people know that they are using the right barcode? How do people check if the barcode is legit? How do you prevent the use of barcodes pointing to another site (prank or attack)? And why don't you use scripts and aliases?

Comment: @nobody it's only a 1D scanner, but that's an interesting idea using a 2D one.

Comment: @xenoid I agree that there's some cons. It's definitely a novelty situation that I wouldn't advocate for everyone. As far as scripts, these are the scripts. As far as aliases, there aren't any because these computers are being set up. I'm trying to focus more on the technical side to see if these commands can be shortened even further.